# .html, .xml, and .txt files getting corrupted: what can be the cause?

Tags: virus

Some important files (.html, .xml, and .txt) appeared blank when opened, but the file size when I check properties remains the same as when the file was good. It happened one time and I recovered from backup copy but then it happened again with 3 more files. I downloaded Avast antivirus and performed drive scan, but found nothing. I checked the files online for viruses and found nothing. I performed test to check drive health status and it came out good. Can anybody give me some light on what the problem can be please? Files are in 8gb Kingston USB flash drive that I bought days ago.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are the files on the Kingston USB drive you mentioned? Where did you get the drive? There is an epidemic of fake USB drives out there; check on sites like [FakeMemorySentinel](https://fakememorysentinel.wordpress.com/2010/02/26/kingston-usb-flash-drives-how-to-check-you-have-a-genuine-one-and-not-a-counterfeit-easy-guide-kingston-technologies-fighting-to-protect-consumers-and-itself-from-counterfeits/) for tools to find if you have a fake drive.

Comment: yes,  they're on the Kingston USB drive. I bought the drive at a local store.  I  used the tool they recommend in  the address you provided (https://www.heise.de/download/product/h2testw-50539) and this is the result (on the next comment):

Comment: The media is likely to be defective.
    3.7 GByte OK (7842752 sectors)
    3.7 GByte DATA LOST (7851072 sectors)
    Details:0.5 KByte overwritten (1 sector)
    0 KByte slightly changed (< 8 bit/sector, 0 sectors)
    3.7 GByte corrupted (7851071 sectors)
    0.5 KByte aliased memory (1 sector)
    First error at offset: 0x0000000000000000
    Expected: 0x0000000000000000
    Found: 0x00000001dd4ffe00
    H2testw version 1.3
    Writing speed: 8.90 MByte/s
    Reading speed: 10.7 MByte/s
    H2testw v1.4

Comment: A classic scam; a 4GB drive they jumpered to show 8GB in Windows. Tell the “local store”; they probably knew this. You must never buy anything from them ever again.